# tensorflow preprocessing with dataset zip issue

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, data-preprocessing

tensorflow preprocessing with dataset zip issue

I just started learning deep learning and came across source code and youtube video showing how the code works by some dude.
https://github.com/nicknochnack/FaceDetection
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_W4EYtsa10&t=5715s

I was trying to preprocess the data using tensorflow's dataset but code seems to get stuck. Not stuck on an infinite loop, not ended with errors, stuck stuck.
So what my code intends to do is get the image from , preprocess it on part_images[partition] like so

```
def load_image(x):
    byte_img = tf.io.read_file(x)
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(byte_img)
    return img

part_images = {}
for partition in ['train','test','val']: 
    part_images[partition] = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("C:/.../"+partition+"/image/*.jpg", shuffle=False)
    part_images[partition] = part_images[partition].map(load_image)
    part_images[partition] = part_images[partition].map(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, (120,120)))
    part_images[partition] = part_images[partition].map(lambda x: x/255)
```

get the label(the bounding box) of the image, preprocess on part_labels[partition]

```
def load_labels(label_path):
    with open(label_path.numpy(), 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        label = json.load(f)
    
    return [label['class']], label['bbox']

part_labels = {}
for partition in ['train','test','val']: 
    part_labels[partition] = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('C:/.../'+partition+'/label/*json', shuffle=False)
    part_labels[partition] = part_labels[partition].map(lambda x: tf.py_function(load_labels, [x], [tf.uint8, tf.float16]))
```

Note that len(part_labels[each of partition]) is same as len(part_images[each of partition])
finally combine the two together with dataset.zip

```
part = {}
for partition in ['train','test','val']: 
    part[partition] = tf.data.Dataset.zip((part_images[partition], part_labels[partition]))
    part[partition] = part[partition].shuffle(int(len(part_images[partition])*1.2))
    part[partition] = part[partition].batch(8)
    part[partition] = part[partition].prefetch(4)
```

nowever, if I try to access the information using as_numpy_iterator(), it doesn't show an error message, doesn't get stuck not in a infinite loop, it just stuck stucks.
When I do keyboard interrupt, with next code, it shows an error like following in case this helps.

```
part['train'].as_numpy_iterator().next()[1]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 part['train'].as_numpy_iterator().next()[1]

File C:\...\test\testEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:4665, in _NumpyIterator.next(self)
   4664 def next(self):
-> 4665   return self.__next__()

File C:\...\test\testEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:4662, in _NumpyIterator.__next__(self)
   4659     numpy.setflags(write=False)
   4660   return numpy
-> 4662 return nest.map_structure(to_numpy, next(self._iterator))

File C:\...\test\testEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py:797, in OwnedIterator.__next__(self)
    795 def __next__(self):
    796   try:
--> 797     return self._next_internal()
    798   except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    799     raise StopIteration

File C:\...\test\testEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py:780, in OwnedIterator._next_internal(self)
    777 # TODO(b/77291417): This runs in sync mode as iterators use an error status
    778 # to communicate that there is no more data to iterate over.
    779 with context.execution_mode(context.SYNC):
--> 780   ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
    781       self._iterator_resource,
    782       output_types=self._flat_output_types,
    783       output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
    785   try:
    786     # Fast path for the case `self._structure` is not a nested structure.
    787     return self._element_spec._from_compatible_tensor_list(ret)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File C:\...\test\testEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py:3038, in iterator_get_next(iterator, output_types, output_shapes, name)
   3036 if tld.is_eager:
   3037   try:
-> 3038     _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
   3039       _ctx, "IteratorGetNext", name, iterator, "output_types", output_types,
   3040       "output_shapes", output_shapes)
   3041     return _result
   3042   except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

This happens with both jupyter and google colab. Only google colab just ignores me when I try keyboard interrupt so I uploaded the jupyter version.